# How to list the keys of given resource bundle (i.e. to say given . properties file) in flex

Tags: actionscript

Is there any way in action script to list all the keys (not values) of given resource bundle.

My use case is to combine content of two different resource bundle. I wan to do this by creating a new resource bundle at runtime and add each key value pair from two different resource bundles into one. I would appreciate if anyone have idea if it can be done different way.

Answer (score 0):

If you get the actual resource bundle (eg. IResourceBundle), you could iterate over the name keys in the content object I would think.